# Since Kirk found Khan much later in the series, how did he get revived early in the movie?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, star-trek-into-darkness

We all have seen Kirk reviving Khan in TOS
But in the latest movie set years before this event we see Khan revived, how is that?
Second part of the question is if he was again sent into space in the capsule?

[Edit]

The other questions set as the original of this duplicate is related to the topic, but is a different question, is this not obvious?

Comment: The question is not if Carol Marcus recognized Khan or not, it was how he got revived early and how it will pan out later, obviously the timeline has changed and both are different stories in two timelines.

Comment: whether the question is the same is not the issue. The *answer* is the same.

Comment: Asking "how it will pan out later" is out of scope for the main site. Someone in the chat room may be willing to speculate with you.

Comment: Well, there's also [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40063/why-did-starfleet-begin-to-aggressively-search-distant-quadrants-of-space)...

Comment: I do not believe this question to be a duplicate

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Admiral Marcus says that after the destruction of Vulcan they started exploring deeper into space and found the Botany Bay with the cryogenically frozen Augments. They revived Khan hoping to use his superior intellect to help them design weapons to protect against powerful enemies such as Nero, using his crew as leverage.

Had the timeline not been altered by Nero in the first movie, the Botany Bay would have remained undiscovered in deep space until the Enterprise found it later, as shown in the TOS episode "Space Seed."

Comment: +1 | This is the answer the movie does not make clear.

Answer (score 6):

Remember that the events from the first film shattered the original series timeline.
So, in this new divergent reality, Khan was being held by Starfleet in cryogenic suspension.
The Starfleet General revived just Khan to use him and he held all of Khan's people frozen as hostages to keep Khan in line.

> At the end of the movie, Khan and all of his followers were put back into cold storage somewhere on Earth.

Comment: "You must unlearn what you have learned..."

Comment: This isn't really an answer. The SS Botany Bay was launched in ~2000, long before the timeline was changed. It's JackBNimble's answer below that actually answers how it was found.

Comment: @Plutor: Of course this is the answer, the OP asked how did he get revived early. And the answer is the disrupted timeline caused starfleet to find him earlier. My answer and Jack's are practically the same.